# Is there a way to use Bootstrap ordering to change what column an element is in in a different breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to accomplish the following effect using Bootstrap order classes:

[image: Diagram of intended div layout]
Presently I'm using something along the lines of this (we can pretend that all of the elements here are of the proper height):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 order-lg-1 order-md-8">First element</div>
    <div class="col-6 order-6">Second element</div>
    <div class="col-3 order-lg-1 order-md-7">Last element</div>
</div>
```

When the display is large, all of the elements should be in a row as seen above. When it's smaller, I want the first and last elements to join into one column.

This structure is obviously possible to do if I join the first and last elements into one element:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-6">Second element</div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div>Last element</div>
        <div>First element</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but then the intended behavior for the large display won't work.

Another option is to duplicate the first element and have it hide and reveal itself based on breakpoints like this:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-3 d-none d-lg-block">First element</div>
    <div class="col-6">Second element</div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div>Last element</div>
        <div class="d-block d-lg-none">First element</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but doing that seems like a bit of a hack. Does anyone know if there's a pure-CSS way to accomplish this?

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="row flex-row-reverse flex-md-row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3  bg-success order-3 order-md-1">First element</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 bg-primary order-2" >Second element Second element Second element</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 bg-warning order-1 order-md-3">Last element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work. When the display shrinks, it simply puts all of the elements in one column.